# The proper way of accessing heavy object members of class

Tags: c#, .net, performance, profiler

I have a class like this:

```
class BuildingFloor
{
    // The list of building rooms;
    // Room is "heavy" object with many-many fields
    List< Room > m_rooms;

    // The list of all apertures on the floor
    List< Aperture > m_apertures;
    ...
    List< Room > Rooms
    {
        get { return m_rooms; }
    }

    List< Aperture > Doors
    {
        get{ return GetAperturesOfType( 2 ); }
    }
    public List< Aperture > Exits
    {
        get{ return GetAperturesOfType( 3 ); }
    }
    ...
    List< Aperture > GetAperturesOfType( int type )
    {
        var apertures = new List<ApertureWrapper>();
        foreach ( var aper in m_apertures )
        {
            if ( ( aper.Type == type ) )
            {
                apertures.Add( aper );
            }
        }
        return apertures;
    }
}
```

My questions are:
1) Will `m_rooms` be copied when client code will access `Rooms` property;
2) How many times `List<>` object will be constructed on the `Doors` property call.

So, what i can change in this code to make it faster?
I need to heavily use these properties in code like
`foreach( var door in m_floor.Doors) { ... }`
NOTE: Profiler says `Exits` property spent significant amount of time. Proof: [image: Visual Studio Profiler screenshot]

Comment: Any reason you put spaces around type arguments? It's very unconventional... (I personally don't like them around the expressions you're using in `if`, `foreach` etc, but that's at least more common. Mind you, you've got a redundant pair of brackets in your `if` condition, too.)

Comment: Side thought: You might consider using a parent class `Aperture` to group common fields and properties into, then extend that class with `DoorAperture`, `WindowAperture`, etc. for properties more specific to those objects.  Its very easy to forget what `apertureType == 2` means six months later...

Comment: @JonSkeet Spaces style based on the C# coding standards on my job. Chief like spaces (many-many spaces) for the unknown reason :)

Comment: @PaulGriffin Do you suggest to use inheritance like Aperture --> Door?

Comment: NOTE: to view full image just open it in the new tab.

Comment: @eraxillan, yes, use inheritance to minimize code redundancy and group common "types" of objects,  i.e. Doors and Windows are both "types" of Apetures, so create a parent class to hold common code (e.g. height and width properties, Open() and Close() methods, whatever they all have in common) and group things together conceptually, then break more specific properties and methods into classes that inherit from it.

Comment: @PaulGriffin Ok, i've understood. Also i'm widely use C# interfaces: e.g. IExtentOwner, any object that has extent (building, floor, room, but not an aperture)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Will m_rooms be copied when client code will access Rooms property

Yes. But the value of `m_rooms` is just a reference - it's not a `List<Room>` object in itself. You might want to read my article about [reference types and value types](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/references.html).

> How many times `List<>` object will be constructed on the Doors property call.

1. It's calling `GetAperturesOfType` once, which constructs a new `List<ApertureWrapper>`.

Your property would be more simply implemented as:

```
return m_apertures.Where(x => x.Type == 2).ToList();
```

(It sounds like you might want an `ApertureType` enum, too...)

Also note that if you *just* need to iterate over the doors, you could just use:

```
return m_apertures.Where(x => x.Type == 2);
```

and avoid creating a `List<>` at all. That would have different semantics in other ways, mind you...

> Profiler says Doors property spent significant amount of time.

Well you'd need to see how many apertures you've actually got, how many are doors, and how often you're calling the `Doors` property. We can't really tell what's significant overall just from what you've shown us. Performance work is usually contextual.

EDIT: Now we've seen the calling code, it would be better if you used a local variable:

```
var exits = m_building.CurrentFloor.Exits;
for (int i = 0; i < exits.Count; i++)
{
    // Use exits[i] within here
    // Set exitId to i + 1 if you find the exit.
    // (Or ideally, change everything to be 0-based...)
}
```

Otherwise you're creating a new list for each iteration of the loop.

Comment: How are you so fast o wise one

Comment: I fix the typo: Exits --> Doors.

Comment: And add the screenshot of the profiler. Hope this made things clear.

Comment: 1) So, *the contents* of `m_room` will not be copied? i.e. the List itself. I've read the article, thanks. So as i understood reference behave like pointer in the C++.<br>
2) Using LINQ, lambdas, IEnurable sounds good, thanks.<br>

Comment: @JonSkeet So, can you comment the profiling results screen please? If List<> object will not copied - only the reference (a pointer), so why it is so slow

Comment: @eraxillan: Well you're calling `Exits` on *every iteration of the loop*. Why do that? Just keep it in a local variable. Basically, you've changed an O(n) loop into an O(n^2) loop... if there are 10 exits, you're building 11 lists with 10 items in each...